# Include announcement's from parent site in subsite announcements

Tags: content-query-web-part, dataview

I'm using Sharepoint Foundation 2010. I'm trying to include announcements from my parent site in my subsite's announcement list. Or atleast in a separate list/webpart above it. If its not possible to completely integrate them together or just inherit the parent announcements in the child's I'd like to just show the 5 most recent parent announcement titles linked to the actual announcements and then maybe a show more button that links to the parent announcement list itself.

I have very very little experience with ASP.net and Sharepoint in general. Sadly I'm unable to use CQWP - that seemed to be able to do what I want to do very easily. I tried using DataView and had no luck. I tried the "VG Content Display" webpart on Codeplex but I could only get it to work with documents not announcement content type for whatever reason. Yes I changed the data type values and such.

I really need to figure this out soon! Please someone tell me the best way to do this with little experience.

Answer (score 1):

It could be achieved via [XsltListViewWebPart (XLV) web part](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.xsltlistviewwebpart).  Basically all you have to do is to specify/update [WebId property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.webpartpages.basexsltlistwebpart.webid) for XLV web part.

> Limitation: it works withing a site collection only

Below id demonstrated how to configure XLV to display list from a sub site using SharePoint Designer (SPD)

### Steps

- open source site in SharePoint Designer (SPD) and go to View page for
  a list/library
- open the page in edit mode and copy XLV declaration:

  ```
  <WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart ...>
  <!-- the remaining code is omitted for a clarity -->
  </WebPartPages:XsltListViewWebPart>
  ```
- open target site via SPD and go to the page where you would like to
  host XLV
- paste the specified XLV declaration into the web part zone
- find WebId attribute and specify Web Id of source site

Answer (score 0):

I have used the webid tip in the past but it is not something I would use as a general practice. SPD is quite buggy in this matter. (still is a nice workaround)

I would recommend creating something like a User Control that can receive the web url and listname as parameters and render the results as required.
This will not only overcome the multi-site problem, but will also provide a resusable, fully customizable solution for the future.

```
using (SPSite site = new SPSite(<url to spweb>))
{
      using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
         SPList announcementsList = web.Lists.TryGetList(<name of list>);
         // put your code here ...
      }
}
```

More info,

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231548.aspx